# Qual é o erro na minha passagem de ponteiro para a função read_vetor()?

Tags: c

```
void read_vetor(int *vet, int n) 
{
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf_s(" %d", *(vet+i));
    }
}

void write_vetor(int* vet, int n)
{
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%d", *(vet+i));
    }
}

void main()
{
    int a[4], b[4];

    printf("Put values for a[4]:    ");
    read_vetor(a, 4);
    printf("Put values for b[4]:    ");
    read_vetor(b, 4);
    write_vetor(a, 4);
    write_vetor(b, 4);

}
```

O meu erro acontece na função read_vector, quando vou a passar o ponteiro, mas não consigo ver o porquê. Alguém me pode ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

As variáveis não devem ser pasadas a função `scanf` por valor. A forma correta seria passar o endereço da variável.

```
scanf_s(" %d", vet + i);
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta!